# Solving a Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to find analytical solution(non-stationary) to the FP equation given below.

$\frac{\partial P(x,t)}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\{[2ae^{-ax}(1-e^{-ax})]P(x,t)]\}+D \frac{\partial^{2}P(x,t)}{\partial x^{2}}$

The boundary conditions are reflecting on the left end and  absorbing on the right. I tried various approaches including finding Green's functions and eigen function expansions. As for Greens function, I tried to find the Fourier transform and I am clueless about how to take the FT of the term $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\{[2ae^{-ax}(1-e^{-ax})]P(x,t)]\}$.

In a nutshell, the question is is it possible to find an analytical solution to the above equation?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Maple 2020** find general solution,expressed by **HeunB** function.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Can you suggest some useful references? And please don't mind if I come up with doubt on this. :-)

Comment: Use Maple and Start a Free Trial: https://www.maplesoft.com/products/maple/students/